# Pullback of D-Modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Hi,

just a short question on the theory of D-Modules:

if one has $p:X\times Y \rightarrow Y$ the projection of two smooth projective complex varieties to the second factor, then what is a $p^{*}D_Y$-Module?

Is this the same as a vectorbundle on $X\times Y$ with an integrable connection relative (!) to $X$?

Comment: It may not be a vector bundle at all; $D$-modules are more complicated.
But if it were, then I suppose you can view it has equipped with a partial connection allowing derivatives along vectors from $Y$.

Comment: $p^\ast D_Y = \mathcal O_X \boxtimes D_Y$, so a $p^\ast D_Y$-module is just a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X\times Y$ with an action of differential operators on $Y$. You could call this a sheaf with a relative connection. As mentioned above, it need not be a vector bundle though.

Comment: I don't know the theory of D-Modules. I think you can assume that it is a vector bundle in my case.
What for me is important is: does the action of differential operators on $Y$ mean that one has a relative connection, namely relative to $X$ (!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was basically answered in the comments.  A $p^*D_Y$-module is a vector bundle with an integrable relative connection on $X \times Y$ if and only if the underlying $\mathcal{O}_{X \times Y}$-module is locally free, i.e., a vector bundle.  In other words, if you are given a vector bundle on $X \times Y$, an action of $p^*D_Y$ is essentially the same data as an integrable relative connection.

You can find a discussion of some of these ideas in [these notes on crystals](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/SeminarNotes/Nov17-19%28Crystals%29.pdf).  The action of $p^*D_Y$ is equivalent to an identification of infinitesimally nearby fibers in the $Y$ direction.

Comment: Not quite: you really need to ask that the underlying $\mathcal{O}_{X\times Y}$-module be a vector bundle. If $Y$ is a point, then a $p^*D_Y$-module is just the same thing as a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$.

Comment: Oops, you're quite right. Fixed.